# jGroups does not join any group on RHEL with link-local ipv6 address

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ipv6, rhel, jgroups

Am seeing this exception in RHEL 7.3.1 when running my code to form a jGroups cluster. The following exception is seen in log.

```
[DEBUG] 2017-10-03 20:23:01.339 [pool-10-thread-1] client.jgroups  - Creating new Channel
[WARN ] 2017-10-03 20:23:01.342 [pool-10-thread-1] stack.Configurator  - JGRP000014: TP.loopback has been deprecated: enabled by default
[DEBUG] 2017-10-03 20:23:01.343 [pool-10-thread-1] stack.Configurator  - set property UDP.bind_addr to default value /fe80:0:0:0:2d57:389e:e4fe:9520%eth0
[DEBUG] 2017-10-03 20:23:01.345 [pool-10-thread-1] stack.Configurator  - set property UDP.diagnostics_addr to default value /ff0e:0:0:0:0:0:75:75
[DEBUG] 2017-10-03 20:23:01.346 [pool-10-thread-1] client.jgroups  - STATE OPEN
[DEBUG] 2017-10-03 20:23:01.347 [pool-10-thread-1] protocols.UDP  - sockets will use interface fe80:0:0:0:2d57:389e:e4fe:9520%eth0
[ERROR] 2017-10-03 20:23:01.374 [pool-10-thread-1] client.jgroups  - Catching
java.lang.Exception: failed to open a port in range 40000-40255
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UDP.createDatagramSocketWithBindPort(UDP.java:500) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UDP.createSockets(UDP.java:361) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.jgroups.protocols.UDP.start(UDP.java:270) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.startStack(ProtocolStack.java:965) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.startStack(JChannel.java:891) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.jgroups.JChannel._preConnect(JChannel.java:553) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:288) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
    at org.jgroups.JChannel.connect(JChannel.java:279) ~[xxx-xxx.jar:2.0.1]
```

Now the same client code runs perfectly on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. Another thing to note is that the following flag is not provided in both the cases.

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Also in both the cases link-local IPv6 addresses are being used.
How to make the same code work on RHEL?

Adding the following info, for the questions asked by @[bela-ban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2309917/bela-ban) : 
Trying options in config xml.

> > I tried both LINK_LOCAL & NON_LOOPBACK, but still getting the same error.

JGroups version?

> > I am using 3.6.3-Final version of JGroups.

Omitting IPv4 flag

> > We have omitted -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, as we want to test our client in an IPv6 client environment.

Running ifconfig -a

> > Also running the command ifconfig -a , gives the following output :

```
ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.66.194.103  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.66.195.255
        inet6 fe80::4b16:4a66:2bc3:c505  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::30cb:2f41:5e04:51c2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fe80::2d57:389e:e4fe:9520  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:b8:65:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8485475  bytes 1961303302 (1.8 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 109087  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 49088  bytes 4169469 (3.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 154252  bytes 11261136 (10.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 154252  bytes 11261136 (10.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: I read this link : http://www.techstacks.com/howto/troubleshoot-jgroups-and-multicast-ip-issues.html. But am not sure how to apply the same advice for link-local addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was all failing due to bad local link addresses.

The first mistake was to use the now obsolete `ifconfig` command. It does not provide any information if the local link addresses assigned are valid or not.

The correct command to use is `ip address`. This command in my case returns the following :

```
# ip address
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:b8:65:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.66.194.103/22 brd 10.66.195.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2d57:389e:e4fe:9520/64 scope link tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::30cb:2f41:5e04:51c2/64 scope link tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4b16:4a66:2bc3:c505/64 scope link tentative dadfailed
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see the ipv6 local link addresses listed here are marked as `tentative dadfailed`. This means that these addresses cannot be used for anything. So the next step was to weed out these bad addresses and add our own unique local address. I did the following steps to accomplish this:

```
#add the new unique local address. Again this can be duplicate, so chose wisely. A reboot may be required after this.
$nmcli c mod eth0 ipv6.addresses fc00::10:8:8:71/7 ipv6.method manual
# Remove out the old local link addresses
$ip address delete fe80::4b16:4a66:2bc3:c505/64 dev eth0
$ip address delete fe80::30cb:2f41:5e04:51c2/64 dev eth0
$ip address delete fe80::2d57:389e:e4fe:9520/64 dev eth0
```

After this we can verify again if the above steps have worked or not

```
ip address show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:b8:65:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.66.194.103/22 brd 10.66.195.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fc00::10:8:8:71/7 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

See no more `tentative dadfailed`.

***Hence, to conclude this was not related to JGroups at all and was only caused by bad local link addresses.***

Answer (score 0):

Which version of JGroups do you use? (`java -cp jgroups.jar org.jgroups.Version` prints the version to stdout).

Using system property `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` will force the use of IPv4 addresses. In your case, on RHEL you seemed to have omitted this property, therefore using IPv6 addresses.

Make sure you do have an address `fe80:0:0:0:2d57:389e:e4fe:9520%eth0` (`ifconfig -a`). Note that you can use `bind_addr=link_local` to pick any link local address.

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual4/index.html#Transport

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried both LINK_LOCAL & NON_LOOPBACK, but still getting the same error. I am using 3.6.3-Final version of JGroups.